# Scala multiple conditions inside when( ) clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val add_Gi = Info.withColumn("Gi",

    when(  
      (col("x") == minX || col("x") == maxX) && (col("y")  == minY || col("y")  == maxY) && (col("z")  == minZ || col("z")  == maxZ), 
      (lit(8.0) * col("count") - X_average*8.0) / ( S * math.sqrt( (8.0*numCells - math.pow(8.0, 2))/(numCells - 1.0) ) )
    )
```

I want to check if a point is in the corner using the code above, but scala keeps give me

```
error >type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Boolean
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

I tried on a simple dataframe on local scala, and when I add three conditions (use && twice), it will also raise the error like that. So I guess I can't use && twice inside same when() clause, is there a way to fix that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: on terminal when compiling the file

Comment: No, I mean, which expression gives you this error?

Comment: the expression before the comma inside the when ( ), at the second && part

Comment: I have no idea where this `when` method comes from, but it looks like its first parameter is supposed to be a `Column` and not a boolean. Can you add to your question which method you're calling?

Comment: You should replace `==`, which would result in a Scala Boolean type, with `===` for a BooleanType Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

scala> df.show
+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|gaurang|
|   shah|
+-------+
```

you can't compare value with column type with `==` operator.

```
scala> df.filter(col("name") == "gaurang").show
<console>:27: error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
       df.filter(col("name") == "gaurang").show
          ^
```

You should use `===` operator

```
scala> df.filter(col("name") === "gaurang").show
+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|gaurang|
+-------+
```